# Finding Scorpius in the Milky Way panorama

Tags: photography, milky-way

I'm searching for the constellation of Scorpius in [this image](https://cdn.eso.org/images/original/eso0932a.tif).

Unfortunately this is a task too hard for a newbie like me, so I would like to have an hand about that.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Astronomy SE, It would be better if you mention what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your reply. I've tried (unsuccessfully) to search Orion's belt in order to get a initial reference point. However there are too many objects in the cited image, and so I'm not even able to find Orion.

Comment: Usually, https://nova.astrometry.net/upload can do this, but it seems to be having trouble with this image (it's still trying though): https://nova.astrometry.net/status/5838124 -- also, although Scorpio did methodologically kill Orion, the two are on opposite sides of the sky, so you wouldn't see Orion's belt anywhere near Scorpio (though I realized the image is large enough that it would also contain Orion's belt)

Comment: Yes, you can find Orion on the right side of the image.

Comment: And Taurus on the left. It's a 360º panoramic image. Given that Scorpio is opposite of both Orion and Taurus, it must be somewhere in the center of the image.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Antares is actually quit easy to spot.  It is just north of the the galactic centre.

Once you have Antares, you can piece together the rest of Scorpio, It is rather hard, because there are *too many stars* but it is there.

[image]

Compare with this screencap from Stellarium

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In that huge picture it can be challenging if you don't know well what is displayed, but you won't have trouble identifying it in the real sky.
Scorpius, the visible common part, it's like a hand where the palm is Antares and it develops three fingers to one side and an arm to the other side.

It's a "hand" coming out of the Milky Way central part.

If you picture it with long exposure, you can even see there is a nebula with 4 colours around Antares. It's the Rho-Ophiucci complex.

There is also a dark nebula in that area, that looks like a river, again, into the Milky Way core.

So always look for the Milky Way core, the brightest part and there, look for the dark arm that leads to a bright hand. Can't miss it!

And there you can maybe ask for directions to a local ;)

Comment: Don't underestimate how the sky in a real dark place looks so much different to what one usually sees in somewhat suburban environments - it can make identification indeed difficult when one is used to one and sees the other.